# Convert GraphPlot[]s with many nodes into something that's human-understandable

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This is more of an abstract/creative problem. I think everyone who has played around with `GraphPlot`, ended up with an image that looks like this, at least once in their life:

[image: messy GraphPlot output]

I am looking for general solutions to convert *many connections* -> *many connections* into something that's human understandable.

Here's my code above:

```
d = DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression["[a-z]{1,5}"]];
d = Take[d, 1000];
g = {};
Do[Do[If[Abs[StringLength[d[[i]]] - StringLength[d[[j]]]] > 1, 
   Continue[]];
  If[EditDistance[d[[i]], d[[j]]] == 1, 
   AppendTo[g, d[[i]] -> d[[j]]];
   AppendTo[g, d[[j]] -> d[[i]]]], {j, i + 1, Length[d]}], {i, 1, 
  Length[d]}]

Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
s = StrongComponents[g];
sc = Last[SortBy[s, Length]];
gc = Select[g, MemberQ[sc, #[[1]]] &];
GraphPlot[gc, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Orange, Arrowheads[Small], 
     Arrow[#1, .07]} &)]
```

I would love something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796279), where strongly connected nodes are grouped into single pie-chart vertices which represent the # of node connections over total connections.

Comment: Your example graph will typically have only a single component of size larger than one, so grouping components into nodes is very likely to just give a star graph in this specific case.

Comment: How about this?

Comment: Well, this one is a connected graph (it has a single connected component).  My point was that you could get better answers if you made the question more specific.  A hairball is a hairball but sometimes it has some underlying structure.  What that structure is and how to extract it will be different from network to network ...  I think the question is too broad to get good answers.

Comment: There's no generic way to extract the underlying structure? I mean, if you gave me a hairball list of data, I would immediately apply generic metrics like mean / mediam / sdev / mode/ etc. to better understand it. It's not my field, so I was wondering if there are generic solutions to handle that these network graphs in the same way. Like grouping closely related connections, and outputting them as pie-charts as 'strength' meters (immediate vs total connections); Or group and play with transparency (weakly connected are barely visible).

Answer (score 9):

Your graph has many vertexes, while the exemplary graph you link to does *not* and this is why it looks so nice. Styling with pie charts is not a problem at all:

```
g = RandomGraph[{15, 43}];

vfc[{xc_, yc_}, name_, {w_, h_}] := 
 Inset[PieChart[{VertexDegree[g, name], VertexList[g] // Length}, 
   SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, .7}, 
   ChartStyle -> "AvocadoColors"], {xc, yc}, Automatic, 
  VertexDegree[g, name]/30]

SetProperty[g, VertexShapeFunction -> vfc]
```

[image]

I by the way understand that you want more - to replace "heavy" sub-graphs by nodes reflecting their statistics. That could be done, but it is a bit messy and ambiguous, more of a research question. If I find time I may post a solution.

Here is another angle at a quicker analysis. Automatic spatial layouts Mathematica uses for graph carry a lot of information too. We can use `FindClusters` to analyse it. I will remove directed and multiple edges for clear picture. To see clustering of regions, after you execute your code do this:

```
n = 10;(*number of clusters*)
grr = Graph[Union[Sort /@ gc], DirectedEdges -> False, GraphStyle -> 
      "LargeNetwork", VertexSize -> 0];
cls = ListPlot[FindClusters[AbsoluteOptions[grr, VertexCoordinates][[2]], n],
      PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]];
Show[grr, cls, BaseStyle -> PointSize[.01]]
```

[image]

Comment: wow looks great! but does this work with GraphPlot? Assuming my Example Graph above is `g = GraphPlot[gc]` (removed Edge Rendering)   and `SetProperty[g, VertexShapeFunction -> vfc]`

Comment: @Mr.DemetriusMichael `Graph` has much greater functionality than `GraphPlot` in the sense that `GraphPlot` is only graphics while `Graph` holds complete information about the graph itself and can be operated upon with various graph-related functions. I'd recommend to use `Graph` for 2D graphs.

Comment: Might I suggest `BaseStyle -> {PointSize[0.01]}, PlotStyle -> Array[ColorData[3], n]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, thanks, should keep it simple ;-)